# Create a Android keystore from a bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I wrote a bat file to generate a keystore via keytool.
My code is:

```
cd C:\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin

set Pass=12345678
set RepetitionPass=test
set FLname=test
set OrganUnit=test
set Organ=test
set City=test
set State=test
set Country=US

set Pass=%Pass: =%
set RepetitionPass=%RepetitionPass: =%
set FLname=%FLname: =%
set OrganUnit=%OrganUnit: =%
set Organ=%Organ: =%
set City=%City: =%
set State=%State: =%
set Pass=%Pass: =%
set Country=%Country: =%

(echo.%Pass% && echo.%RepetitionPass% && echo.%FLname% && echo.%OrganUnit% && echo.%Organ% && echo.%City% && echo.%State% && echo.%Country% && echo y)| keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
pause
```

I put this code inside Notepad and then changed its extension to .bat.
Everything works fine My only problem is that the end of a space password is automatically added. For example, if my password is "12345678", when the key is generated, its password will be "12345678 ".
For some reason, I do not want to use Android Studio to generate the key, and I must produce my Key Store this way.
where is the problem from? How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Notwithstanding, the fact that your first line should be `CD /D "C:\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin"`, and lines `3` to `10`, and lines `12` to `20`, should all use the recommended syntax, `Set "varName=strValue"`, line `22` has several instances of `<space>&&` which should be replaced with just `&`. Essentially only your last submitted line does not require syntax improvement! In summary, you are `echo`ing a trailing space with each variable, then complaining about those trailing spaces.

Comment: Examples: `Set "Pass=12345678"`, and `(Echo(%Pass%& Echo(%RepetitionPass%& Echo(%FLname%& Echo(%OrganUnit%& Echo(%Organ%& Echo(%City%& Echo(%State%& Echo(%Country%& Echo y)| keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`.

Comment: Why in the world are you using `&&` to chain commands together when you're already using a code block and piping it to `keytool`? Just put everything on its own line but keep it inside of the parentheses.

Comment: Also, please don't use lazy commands, `keytool` should be more like `"%ProgramFiles%\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool.exe"`. A batch file is written only once, there's no need for non robust shorthand which relies on the end users system or user variables in order to work as intended.

Comment: There is no one to answer?

Comment: I've provided your exact code syntax and examples for every one of your lines, _(except for `pause`)_ @Android. Instead of commenting, make the changes I've advised, and then feedback!

Comment: @Android essentially the problem with your code is a TYPO.  When we see that we flag the answer to be closed as a TYPO.  Instead of providing an answer below we will put the answer or fragment in a comment which Compo provided to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows Command Prompt is rather sensitive to <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>, so when you provide such, they may have some effect. For instance: `echo foo & echo bar` will output a line `foo` + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and a line `bar` (given that there is no "invisible" trailing <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, of course).

But the situation at hand is even more complicated: You have got a pipe (`|`) involved in your batch script, which will initiate a new `cmd.exe` instance for the left side since there is a parenthesised block<sup>1</sup>; this new instance receives the left code somehow rebuilt, so even more unwanted <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> become inserted. Returning to the previous example, `(echo foo&echo bar) | more` would return even both lines with a trailing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> each<sup>2</sup>, because the left command would become rebuilt as something like `( echo foo & echo bar )`.

Even the following would still return a trailing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> per line:

```cmd
(
    echo foo
    echo bar
) | more
```

since the command block on the left side would again become rebuilt to something like `( echo foo & echo bar )`.

---

A possible solution is to [escape](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) the ampersand, so it becomes passed over to the new `cmd.exe` instance literally without modification:

```cmd
(echo foo^& echo bar) | more
```

Obviously this only prevents the first line from being appended with a <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, but when we append another escaped ampersand plus a command that literally does nothing, like [`rem/`](https://ss64.com/nt/rem.html)<sup>3</sup>, the solution is complete:

```cmd
(echo foo^& echo bar^& rem/) | more
```

The same can also be applied to the block approach:

```cmd
(
    echo foo^& rem/
    echo bar^& rem/
) | more
```

which would eventually become translated to something like `( echo foo& rem/ & echo bar& rem/ )`.

---

Now let us apply this to your code, together with another few changes:

- The [`cd` command](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) requires the `/D` option in order to change the current drive as well, and quoting paths is generally a good practice. Also consider what to do when the path does not exist or cannot be accessed for some reason ([conditional execution `&&` or `||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) may serve here).
- You should generally prefer the quoted syntax of the [`set` command](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html), like `set "Pass=12345678"` instead of `set Pass=12345678`, in order to protect special characters and to avoid unwanted trailing <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>.
- I entirely skipped the code block for removal of <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>, because I assume this was just a failed attempt to remove the unwanted <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> in the output (if you do want that block, you should use the quoted syntax like `set "Pass=%Pass: =%"` rather than `set Pass=%Pass: =%`).
- Although widely used, `echo.` is a bad way of echoing a (potentially) empty line, because a file called `echo.` is actually searched before the internal command [`echo`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) becomes executed. If, for whatever reason, such a file exists, it is attempted to be executed instead. Therefore, use the syntax `echo(`, which looks odd but is safe.
- You do not need conditional execution to chain `echo` commands, an unconditional `&` operator is fine.

So here is the probably fixed code:

```cmd
@echo off
cd /D "C:\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin" || exit /B

set "Pass=12345678"
set "RepetitionPass=test"
set "FLname=test"
set "OrganUnit=test"
set "Organ=test"
set "City=test"
set "State=test"
set "Country=US"

(
    echo(%Pass%^& rem/
    echo(%RepetitionPass%^& rem/
    echo(%FLname%^& rem/
    echo(%OrganUnit%^& rem/
    echo(%Organ%^& rem/
    echo(%City%^& rem/
    echo(%State%^& rem/
    echo(%Country%^& rem/
    echo y^& rem/
) | keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
pause
```

---

<sub>1)  For a detailed explanation refer to this post: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133) (see phase 5.3)</sub>
<sub>2)  Write the output into a file using [output redirection (`>`)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) in order to prove it.</sub>
<sub>3)  It has to be `rem/` and not `rem`, because the latter would comment out the whole remainder of the command line.</sub>